# DateTime changes by Breeze before save changes

Tags: datetime, breeze, momentjs

I am creating a new Entity and inside constructor I set the datetime like

```
function Project() {
    this.created = moment().format();
}
```

which produce a result in console the current date and time

```
Sat Jun 07 2014 18:48:41 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
```

As soon as I call save changes and see the posted date in the network tabe it changes the hour part of datetime `2014-06-07T13:48:41.000Z`

It looks like Breeze does this, may be I am wrong, Any suggestion how can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: What's the problem?  Breeze is just serializing the date for transport It is not transformed at all.  If you look it is 5 hours different in UTC meaning it will localize out the same when you moment.format it again

Comment: No, when I format the datetime again, it produces a result Sat Jun 07 2014 13:48:41 . I want the actual one i.e Sat Jun 07 2014 18:48:41

Comment: Can you please show me, how do I get localize date?

Answer (score 1):

Breeze is just serializing the date for transport It is not transformed at all. If you look it is 5 hours different in UTC meaning it will localize out the same when you `moment.format` it again.

If you want to re-localize it just use `moment(yourDate).format(LL)` or something similar.

http://momentjs.com/ and go to Internationalization section

Comment: I used this to format moment(myDate).format('MMMM Do YYYY h:mm:ss a') but the output date appears to be Sat Jun 07 2014 1:48:41pm..It should be Sat Jun 07 2014 6:48:41pm

Comment: Don't use that format use the one I showed or LLLL instead

Comment: I used LL that only show the date part which is good, but using LLL shows date and time with the same output above.

Comment: sorry mistake in typo. using LLLL shows date and time with the same output above